# Audio and video track doesn't match in Premier pro

Tags: premiere, video-editor, adobe, production, video-production

I use Movavi for screen recording and after recording it's about 7 min video of the tutorial. I played in VLC media player it's fine perfectly matched audio and video. (Audio and the video track is same and has not been manipulated — captured from Movavi Software).

And for editing, I create a new project in Adobe Premiere Pro, and when I import my clip to timeline I can see that the starting point and ending point of that video and audio clip are the same. But when I play that clip Video is delayed why is that? And when I play at last around 5-sec track it's fine.

Can you guys assist me what's the problem? I tried many creating many new projects to start from default but no progress. I guess I must have messed something up, Couldn't figure out what is that.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a performance issue.

You could change playback resolution, quality, use proxy videos, render preview videos and some more. Tutorials for these steps should be easy to find.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of reasons for this problem.
I have found this useful thread from Adobe.

[Audio and Video not matching](https://community.adobe.com/t5/premiere-pro-discussions/audio-and-video-speed-not-matching-how-to-sync/td-p/10908974)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).